# Tarski's notion of $E$-space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am reading Tarski's paper "Sequential Calculus and Topology". In it he defines an *$E$-space* to be a topological space such that for any non-empty open set $A$ and for any $n \ge 1$, there exist non-empty pairwise disjoint open sets $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ such that

(i) $B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_n \subseteq A$ but $B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_n \neq A$,

(ii) $\overline{A \setminus (B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_n)} \supseteq \overline{A} \setminus A$,

(iii) $\overline{B}_1 \cap \ldots \cap \overline{B}_n \supseteq A \setminus (B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_n)$.

Here I've modernised Tarski's set notation but followed him in writing $\overline{X}$ for the closure of $X$. Tarski uses the closure operator to define his notion of topological space and includes the axiom $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$, so his spaces are all $T_1$.

Tarski proves that if a space with a countable basis is normal and dense-in-itself, then it is an $E$-space. The proof is not trivial, even for the case $n = 1$. Google finds me a link to a book chapter that says "$E$-space" is another name for a Fréchet-Urysohn space (i.e., one in which the sequential closure operation is the same as the ordinary closure operation). I cannot see any obvious connection between the two notions. Are they equivalent?

Any other information or references relating to Tarski's notion of $E$-space would be appreciated?

Comment: Is Tarksi's paper readable online? For what purpose does he introduce it? To solve what problem?

Comment: The paper is available in the German original [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm31/fm31113.pdf) - see the first few pages of section 3. He is identifying a class of topological spaces that can be used to construct a class of Heyting algebras that characterise intutionistic propositional logic.

Comment: Aha, there must be a connection to logic of course :)

Comment: Are there any examples beyond crowded metrisable spaces? I cannot think of any, It would make it a pretty boring class if there weren't. I don't see Tarski mentioning this...In 3.11 he had a chance but no...

Comment: In the indiscrete part (which is open) there cannot be disjoint open sets so $n=2$ fails for it, right? Even $n=1$ come to think it.

Comment: Yes, you're right: I wasn't thinking straight about the indiscrete part. I'll have to think harder about non-metrisable examples.

Comment: The [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) must surely be an example of a non-metrisable $E$-space. You can do the open intervals that are components of an open set separately and you can then treat each open interval as an open interval in $\Bbb{R}$ by treating a long enough closed subinterval $C$ as a single point $x$, applying Tarski's proof and then replacing $x$ by the elements of $C$ in whichever of the $B_i$ contains $x$.

Comment: So locally Euclidean might be good enough.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: surely examples like a wedge of circles show that locally Euclidean is not a necessary condition for a space to be one of Tarski's $E$-spaces.